# get hostname in lotus notes using @formula

Tags: lotus-formula

get hostname in lotus notes using @formula. for eg. http://WDLR11/sample.nsf/burntest.xsp.I want to get the WDLR11

Answer (score 0):

You could start with [@ServerName](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SERVERNAME_FUNCTION.html).  It'll return a canonicalized name that includes the server name (eg: `cn=WDLR11/ou=servers/o=someorg`).  Wrapping [@Name](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NAME.html) around that will allow you to get what you want (ie: `@Name( [cn]; @ServerName );` would return "WDLR11" in this example ).

The thing to note is if your server is actually `cn=AServer/ou=servers/o=someorg` running on host `WDLR11`, you'll need to publish an internal dns entry for `AServer` so your computed url ( http://AServer/sample.nsf/burntest.xsp ) will still work.

Failing that you could do some lookups into the server's Domino Directory (`names.nsf`) and pull the host name out of the server config but that's only worth doing if `@ServerName` doesn't give you what you want.

Comment: @LRE-Thank you. I will try this one.

Comment: will the @formula reutnr the hostname if I run my database in my local?the return value was blank

Comment: on a local database it should return the user name.  On a server db opened from your local client I'd expect to work as described above.